# how to set width of li based on its longest contents width

Tags: jquery, css

i hav an unordered list whose contents are filled dynamically from database using below in code behind

```
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    int lastDepth = -1;
    int numUL = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        int currentDepth = Convert.ToInt32(row["Depth"]);
        if (lastDepth < currentDepth)
        {
            output.Append("<ul class=\"dropdown\">");
            numUL++;
        }
        else if (lastDepth > currentDepth)
        {
            output.Append("</li></ul></li>");
            numUL--;
        }
        else if (lastDepth > -1)
        {
            output.Append("</li>");
        }
        output.AppendFormat("<li><span class=\"text\"><a href=\"{1}\" title={1}>{0}</a></span>", row["ApplicationName"], row["Url"]);

       lastDepth = currentDepth;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= numUL; i++)
    {
        output.Append("</li></ul>");
    }
    Literal1.Text = output.ToString();
```

In above code "dropdown" is the class i used to style the ul...everything is workin fine.......

above code returns unordered list lke this

```
<ul>Home
<li><a href="#">Country</a></li>
<li>State</li>
<li>City</li>
</ul>
```

i have a bit more ul's coming similarly from database.the problem is i need to set the longest content width as width of li coming under ul
for example:Country is longest above so the width of all the li's coming under "Home"
should hav the same width....

the styling is done over here to create a good lookin navigation bar in external css

```
ul.dropdown                         {text-align:left; position:relative;z-index:1; }

ul.dropdown li                      { font-weight: bold;border:1px solid green; float:left;color:white;background: black; }

ul.dropdown a:hover                 { color: white; }

ul.dropdown a:active                { color: white; }

ul.dropdown li a                    { text-align:left; display:inline; padding:4px;
                                      color:white;}

ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } 


ul.dropdown li:hover                { background: orange; color: white; position:relative; }



.dropdown ul                        {  visibility:hidden; 

position:absolute;  left: 0; }

ul.dropdown ul li                   
{ font-weight: normal; background:black; color: white; float:left; }


ul.dropdown ul li a{color:White; border-right: none;display: inline-block; } 


ul.dropdown ul ul                   { left: 100px; top: 0; }

ul.dropdown li:hover > ul           { visibility: visible;}
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JavaScript/jQuery after the document has been loaded to find the width of the largest li element and then set all the list elements' width to that value.

EDIT: The below code won't work as is since element.css('width') returns "40px". You'll have to trim the "px" off the end.
EDIT 2: I've fixed the code.

Something like this: (change the 'li' selector to whatever you need)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var maxWidth = 0;
        var elemWidth = 0;
        $('li').each(function() {
            elemWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (parseInt($(this).css('width')) > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = elemWidth;
            }
        });
        $('li').each(function() {
            $(this).css('width', maxWidth + "px");
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Jack how do i select the li selector..i have done like this    $(document).ready(function() {
        var maxWidth = 0;
        var elemWidth = 0;
        $('li.text').each(function() {
            elemWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (parseInt($(this).css('width')) > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = elemWidth;
            }
        });
        $('li.text').each(function() {
            $(this).css('width', maxWidth + "px");
        });
    });
since text is the class for li i have mentioned in code behind i hav used li.text as selector...it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems you have a span inside of the "li" element. This span has the class "text", not the actual "li" element. You'd have to change this around somehow. Your code is correct for when the list element also has the class "text". $('li .text') would select the li's descendants with class "text". However, you'd be modifying the span's width instead of the li's width. I'm not sure that's what you intend to do.

Comment: @Jack i have removed span and class text..how do i call the li now?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
        var maxWidth = 0;
        var elemWidth = 0;
        $("ul.dropdown li a").each(function() {
            elemWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (parseInt($(this).css('width')) > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = elemWidth;
            }
        });
        $("ul.dropdown li a").each(function() {
            $(this).css('width', maxWidth + "px");
        });
    });   ...i m using ul.dropdown li a...but the width is almost zero for all the categories

Comment: @Jack the code you hav given is setting same width to all the li's(li's that have <a></a>)and the width is set to zero.....i  canot see the contents...as i hav mentioned earlier i have changed the selector to "ul.dropdown li a" instead of li.text and removed the span..the width applied to all the different children coming under different parent and the width is zero...i have removed the class text too...i guess im callin all the li's at the same time..need help..than q..

Comment: ihve made changes to code u gav to make it work for individual parent li's >>>>> $(document).ready(function() {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    $("ul.dropdown li").each(function() {
        $("ul.dropdown ul li").each(function() {
                           var x = ($(this).outerWidth());
                            if(x>maxWidth)
                            {
                            maxWidth=x;
                            }
                            //alert(maxWidth);
                            
            });
            $("ul.dropdown ul li").css('width', maxWidth);
        });

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual width of the items wont be determined until runtime and you have to set a hard width for the dropdowns to work correctly i would iterate over the list items after you append them to the dom and find the longest with then call `element.css('width', widthoflongest)` on the parent li.